# Making the edges of the visnetwork diagram straight in R

Tags: javascript, r, igraph, vis.js, visnetwork

The given visNetwork script creates the visNetwork plot as in the snapshot below. My issue is such that if you see the first and second node, the edge between the two is curved. Is there a way I can possibly make the edges straight without changing the length of the edge. Attaching the snapshot for reference, Please help.

```
library(visNetwork)
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:10,color = c(rep("blue",6), rep("red",3), 
rep("green",1)))
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), to = 
c(2,3,4,8,5,6,7,8,9,10),length = c(2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
nodes = data.frame(nodes, level = edges$from)
visNetwork(nodes, edges, height = "500px", width = "100%") %>% 
visOptions(highlightNearest = list(enabled = T, degree = 2, hover = T)) %>%
visOptions(highlightNearest = F, nodesIdSelection = F, width = 500, height = 
500,autoResize = F) %>%
visEdges(smooth = T) %>% 
addFontAwesome() %>% visHierarchicalLayout(edgeMinimization = T,  
blockShifting = T , levelSeparation = 89 ) %>% 
visEdges(shadow = TRUE,
         arrows =list(to = list(enabled = TRUE, scaleFactor = 2)),
         color = list(color = "black", highlight = "red")) %>%
visLayout()
```

[image: Visnetwork capture diagram]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set `visEdges()`'s `smooth=` argument to `FALSE`: `visEdges(smooth = FALSE)`

```
library(visNetwork)

nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:10,color = c(rep("blue",6), 
                                        rep("red",3), 
                                        rep("green",1)))
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
                    to = c(2,3,4,8,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                    length = c(2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
nodes <- data.frame(nodes, level = edges$from)

visNetwork(nodes, edges, 
           height = "500px", width = "100%",
           main = "Straight Edges") %>% 
  visHierarchicalLayout(edgeMinimization = T,
                        blockShifting = T , 
                        levelSeparation = 89 ) %>%
  visEdges(
    # =========================
           smooth = FALSE, # ========================= straight edges
    # =========================
           shadow = TRUE,
           arrows =list(to = list(enabled = TRUE, scaleFactor = 2)),
           color = list(color = "black", highlight = "red")
    )
```

[image: Straight Edges Visualization]

Comment: Thanks, Appreciate your efforts here.